# What does $(A_1-\{a_1\},<_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2)$ mean in this context?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading a proof of theorem 4.3 from textbook *Introduction to set theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

> I have searched through the book from the beginning up to this theorem, but I have not found this notation before. Please explain what $(A_1-\{a_1\},<_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2)$ possibly means!

Comment: This is the restriction of the relation to the subset $A_1\setminus \{a_1\}$.

Comment: Hi @Wuestenfux, from your hint, i understand that we restrict relation $<_1$ to the Cartesian product $(A_1 - \{a_1\})\times(A_1 - \{a_1\})$. I don't understand why the author use $\cap$ since $\cap$ usually denotes the intersection.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Is it better or clearer if we use $(A_1-\{a_1\},{<_1}_{\restriction(A_1-\{a_1\})^2})$?

Comment: It doesn't help that the spacing is off. The author forgot to put curly braces around `<_1` so TeX would know this was being used as the name of a set rather than an infix relation symbol. Compare the spacing: $${<_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2} \qquad\text{versus}\qquad {{<_1}\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2}$$

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm! I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\leq$ is a relation, and a relation on $A$ is a subset of $A^2$.

So, $(A_1-\{a_1\}, \leq_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2)$ is the set $(A_1-\{a_1\}$ with the relation $\leq_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2$. If we define $\leq_{1*}$ as $$\leq_{1*}: =\leq_1\cap(A_1-\{a_1\})^2$$

then $$x\leq_{1*}y\iff x\leq_1y$$ for all $x,y\in A_1$ so long as $x,y\neq a_1$. In short, $\leq_{1*}$ is simply the relation $\leq_1$, restricted to $A_1$.

Comment: I don't understand the intention of authors when they use $\cap$ since $\cap$ usually denotes the intersection of sets. Why don't they use $\restriction$ instead?

Comment: @LeAnhDung A relation is a set. A subset of $A^2$. So why not use $\cap$?

Comment: Oh I got it! The authors meant that the newly defined relation is the intersection of $<_1$ and $(A_1-\{a_1\})^2$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Exactly.